# Can I recreate_versions original file exists using CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave in rails for ImageUpload.

I want to resize original image file because of the file size.

So I remove version :thumb block position process code not in version block like below.

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  ..
  #version :thumb do
  #  process :resize_to_limit => [1024, nil]
  #end

  process :resize_to_limit => [1024, nil] # added not in version block
  ..
end
```

Problem is I don't know **how to recreate original image file exists** and uploaded from using CarrierWave.

.recreate_versions! method only works to version block I think..

```
#mounted uploader above
model.list_image.recreate_versions!
# => [:store_versions!]
# original file not change
```

How to recreate original file already exist ?

(I don't want to add version block because if add version block, then whenever a image file is uploaded the image file is more than one file. (original file and specific version files) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem with two ways :

1. You can call save event in a loop for all object and in your model where image present resize your actual image using imagemagick (RMagick).

   ```
   class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
     before_save do
       self.image = self.image.resize "1024x"
     end
   end
   ```
2. You will create new record for all image related data and destroy previous one. instead of using `recreate_versions` method.

   ```
   Model.all.each { |old|
     new = Modle.new(foo_id: old.foo_id, image: old.image)
     new.save!
     old.destroy
   }
   ```